# How to connect in the instance of RDS database in aws public, accessibility don't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How to connect to an instance to a database?

I followed the tutorial, manual and video:

- [Creating an Amazon RDS DB Instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html)
- [Connecting to a DB Instance Running the PostgreSQL Database Engine - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html)

When I follow and create the instance for testing even with the public accessibility enabled, when I will try to make the connection through `pgAdmin`, due to the timeout error. I have to make some more configuration for the connection?

- **Endpoint (Host)**: `database-teste.c4uzzi1gwwoz.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com`
- **Port**: `5432`

Comment: Never put private credentials online. I suggest you immediately change the password for that database, or even delete the database.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the configuration of the Security Group associated with your database. It should allow an Inbound connection on port 5432 from your IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, put as credentials just to reproduce the problem because it is a temporary bank, but thanks for the help, I will try to do this because in other clouds I needed to put the ip that could access the bank should be this then

Answer (score 0):

change the security group, in the entry and exit rules, modify the type of postgresSql and change the source of my IP inside box select on both, and set the port range to 5432